# angular what is the clean way to hide components based on condition?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Good day. I have a scenario where components are being shown depending on the condition, I am looking for a clear way ang optimized way to do this. I have a service below that will check 3 conditions like if user exists in the same account , user exists in other account and user does not exists on any account.

if user exists with other account show div 1 and hide div 2 and div 3. If user does not exists on any account show div 2 and hide div 1 and div 3. If user exists in the same account then hide all div.

The showing and hiding of div show always trigger as long as getStarted function is called. Any idea guys ? Thank you.

#let us say I have 3 divs

```
<div class="1">
</div>


<div class="2">
</div>

<div class="3">
</div>

 getStarted() {
    if (this.userService) {
      this.userService.checkUserEmail(this.accountId,email).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          if (res.isSuccess === false) {
            console.log("user already exists on this account")
          } else if (res.isSuccess === true) {
           console.log("user exists on another account")
          } else {
            console.log("User does not exist on any accounts")
          }
        },
        (err: any) => {
           this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a property like 'userStatus' in componenet ts file and assign values to it from the API response like below, read those respective values in HTML template and compare them using `*ngIf`. This is very simple version of the implementation, you can use enums as well for probable values. which `userStatus` property can hold. However below code will work perfectly for you.

```
userStatus:string;
getStarted() {
    if (this.userService) {
      this.userService.checkUserEmail(this.accountId,email).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          if (res.isSuccess === false) {
            userStatus = 'USER_EXISTS'
            console.log("user already exists on this account")
          } else if (res.isSuccess === true) {
            userStatus = 'USER_ON_OTHER_ACCOUNT'
           console.log("user exists on another account")
          } else {
            userStatus = 'USER_ON_NO_ACCOUNT'
            console.log("User does not exist on any accounts")
          }
        },
        (err: any) => {
           this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
    }
  }
```

and in html

```
<div *ngIf="userStatus == 'USER_EXISTS'"></div>
<div *ngIf="userStatus == 'USER_ON_OTHER_ACCOUNT'"></div>
<div *ngIf="userStatus == 'USER_ON_NO_ACCOUNT'"></div>
```

Comment: why use string instead of boolean userStatus  Sir ?

Comment: boolean can have two values only, but your use case have three conditions.

Comment: if you want a "more elegant" you can take a look to this link: https://netbasal.com/the-power-of-structural-directives-in-angular-bfe4d8c44fb1

Comment: bro one last question, how do we achieve this mat card color using css https://imgur.com/a/Z5JpVuh . The style I have is style="box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);margin-top: 30px; but it seems not the same.

Comment: I request you to please post another question, as I am unable to open this URL, and somebody else having css expertise may help on you on this query